# Implementing median cut using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, compression

So I'm trying to implement a basic median cut algorithm in python using python and numpy so far i got some simple code to calculate which medians i need to calculate

```
img = ...
per = [100.0/(cuts+2)*i for i in range(1,cuts+1)]
med = np.percentile(img,per)
```

however I now want to convert the image to values between 0 and `cuts` where 0 is the would represent the lowest median and `cuts-1` the highest.

Edit:

`img` is a grayscale image represented as a matrix

Answer (score -1, accepted):

at the risk of sounding like a smartass ... you have looked at?:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html

I would assume you can load the image as a data-grid (pandas) or an array with numpy.  And then pass the iterable into a desired stat function ...